# Issues with monitoring web services on Spring Admin with SSL enabled

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, https, netflix-eureka

I am currently running three web services using Spring Boot 2. They are on different port numbers. However one of them has the following config:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 60
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    statusPageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/actuator/info'
    healthCheckUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/actuator/health'
    homePageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/'
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 30
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://system:****@localhost:8761}/eureka/
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS

server:
  port: 1234
  ssl:
    key-store: keystore.jks
    key-store-password: ******
    keyStoreType: JKS
```

Spring admin can still detect the web service but it's status shows up as "DOWN" even though I know that it is up and running just fine.

Is there anything that I am missing from the config?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your configuration, it should allow your https microservices to register to Eureka.

```
eureka:
   instance: 
      nonSecurePortEnabled: false
      securePortEnabled: true
      statusPageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/info'
      healthCheckUrl:'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/health'
      homePageUrl: 'https://${eureka.instance.hostName}:${server.port}/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still getting the same issue. I have updated my config to resemble your suggestions. Before I had posted up a partial config. I have now update to show the whole 'eureka' config